# C++ std::any Implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++20

Took a shot at implementing `std::any`. I think this should cover a majority of the functionality of the standard version, except there may be some missing auxiliary functions, and the overload resolution may not be exactly as is written in the standard.

```
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

struct bad_any_cast: std::exception {
    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return "bad_any_cast: failed type conversion using AnyCast";
    }
};

class Any {
public:
    constexpr Any() noexcept = default;

    template<typename T, typename Decayed = std::decay_t<T>>
    requires(!std::is_same_v<Decayed, Any>)
    Any(T&& value) {
        m_holder = std::make_unique<holder<Decayed>>(std::forward<T>(value));
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    Any(std::in_place_type_t<T> type, Args&&...args) {
        emplace<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    Any(const Any& other) {
        if (other.m_holder) {
            m_holder = std::unique_ptr<base_holder>(other.m_holder->clone());
        }
    }

    Any& operator=(const Any& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            Any temp{other};
            swap(temp);
        }
        
        return *this;
    }

    Any(Any&& other) noexcept : m_holder(std::move(other.m_holder)) {}

    Any& operator=(Any&& other) noexcept {
        if (this != &other) {
            m_holder = std::move(other.m_holder);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args) {
        m_holder = std::make_unique<holder<T>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void swap(Any& other) noexcept {
        std::swap(m_holder, other.m_holder);
    }

    void reset() noexcept {
        m_holder.reset();
    }
    
    bool has_value() const noexcept {
        return bool(*this);
    }

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
        return m_holder != nullptr;
    }

    ~Any() = default;
    

private:
    template<typename U>
    friend U AnyCast(const Any& value);

    template<typename U>
    friend U AnyCast(Any& value);

    template<typename U>
    friend U AnyCast(Any&& value);

    template<typename U>
    friend U* AnyCast(Any* value);

    struct base_holder {
        virtual const std::type_info &type() const noexcept = 0;
        virtual base_holder* clone() const = 0;
        virtual ~base_holder() = default;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct holder: base_holder {
        template<typename U>
        holder(U&& value): 
            item{std::forward<U>(value)} {}

        template<typename... Args>
        holder(Args&&... args): 
            item{T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)} {}
        
        holder* clone() const override {
            return new holder<T>{std::move(item)};
        }
        
        const std::type_info &type() const noexcept override {
            return typeid(T);
        }

        T item;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<base_holder> m_holder;    
};

template<typename T>
T AnyCast(const Any& value) {
    if (value.m_holder->type() != typeid(T)) {
        throw bad_any_cast();
    }

    return dynamic_cast<Any::holder<T>&>(*value.m_holder).item;
}

template<typename T>
T AnyCast(Any&& value) {
    if (value.m_holder->type() != typeid(T)) {
        throw bad_any_cast();
    }

    return dynamic_cast<Any::holder<T>&>(*value.m_holder).item;
}

template<typename T>
T AnyCast(Any& value) {
    if (value.m_holder->type() != typeid(T)) {
        throw bad_any_cast();
    }

    return dynamic_cast<Any::holder<T>&>(*value.m_holder).item;
}

template<typename T>
T* AnyCast(Any* value) {
    if (!value || value->m_holder->type() != typeid(T)) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return &(dynamic_cast<Any::holder<T>&>(*value->m_holder).item);
}

template<typename T, typename...Args>
Any makeAny(Args&&... args) {
    return Any(std::in_place_type<T>, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The class is very popular with lots of friends, most of which do very similar things. Is there some way I can consolidate this? Why is `any_cast` a separate function and not part of the class anyway?

Finally, some tests partially inspired by cppreference examples.

````
#ifdef BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#else
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#endif // BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/test/data/monomorphic.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>

#include "Any.h"

struct A {
    int age;
    std::string name;
    double salary;

    A(int age, std::string name, double salary)
        : age(age), name(std::move(name)), salary(salary) {}
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(default_constructor_test) {
    Any a;
    BOOST_CHECK(!a);
    BOOST_CHECK(!a.has_value());
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(basic_int_test) {
    Any a{7};
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<int>(a), 7);
    BOOST_CHECK(a.has_value());
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(in_place_type_test) {
    Any a(std::in_place_type<A>, 30, "Ada", 1000.25);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a).age, 30);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a).name, "Ada");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a).salary, 1000.25);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(bad_cast_test) {
    Any a{7};
    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(AnyCast<float>(a), bad_any_cast);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(type_change_test) {
    Any a{7};
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<int>(a), 7);
    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(AnyCast<std::string>(a), bad_any_cast);

    a = std::string("hi");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<std::string>(a), "hi");
    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(AnyCast<int>(a), bad_any_cast);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(reset_test) {
    Any a{7};
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<int>(a), 7);

    a.reset();
    BOOST_CHECK(!a.has_value());
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(pointer_test) {
    Any a{7};
    int *i = AnyCast<int>(&a);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*i, 7);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(emplacement_test) {
    Any a;
    BOOST_CHECK(!a.has_value());

    a.emplace<A>(30, "Ada", 1000.25);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a).age, 30);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a).name, "Ada");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a).salary, 1000.25);

    a.emplace<A>(50, "Bob", 500.5);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a).age, 50);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a).name, "Bob");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a).salary, 500.5);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(swap_test) {
    Any a1{7};
    Any a2{A{30, "Ada", 1000.25}};

    a1.swap(a2);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<int>(a2), 7);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a1).age, 30);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a1).name, "Ada");
    BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(AnyCast<A>(a1).salary, 1000.25, 0.0001); // Use BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE for floating point comparisons
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(make_any_test) {
    Any a1 = makeAny<int>(7);
    Any a2 = makeAny<A>(30, "Ada", 1000.25);

    a1.swap(a2);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<int>(a2), 7);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a1).age, 30);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a1).name, "Ada");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<A>(a1).salary, 1000.25);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(move_test) {
    Any a1{42};
    Any a2{std::move(a1)};
    BOOST_CHECK(!a1.has_value());
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<int>(a2), 42);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(copy_test) {
    Any original{A{30, "Ada", 1000.25}};
    Any copy{original};
    A original_casted = AnyCast<A>(original);
    A copy_casted = AnyCast<A>(copy);

    original_casted.age = 40;
    BOOST_CHECK_NE(original_casted.age, copy_casted.age);
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(self_assignment_test) {
    Any a{5};
    a = a; // self-assignment
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<int>(a), 5);
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(nested_any_test) {
    Any inner{42};
    Any outer;
    outer.emplace<Any>(inner);

    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(AnyCast<int>(outer), bad_any_cast);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<Any>(outer).has_value(), true);
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(large_object_test) {
    std::vector<int> largeVector(1000000, 5);  // A vector with 1 million ints.
    Any a{largeVector};
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<std::vector<int>>(a).size(), 1000000);
}


static int destructorCounter = 0;
struct TestDestruction {
    ~TestDestruction() {
        destructorCounter++;
    }
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(destructor_call_test) {
    {
        Any a;
        a.emplace<TestDestruction>();
    }  // scope to ensure a is destroyed
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(destructorCounter, 1);
}

struct ExceptionThrower {
    ExceptionThrower() {
        throw std::runtime_error("Exception during construction");
    }
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(exception_safety_test) {
    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(Any a{ExceptionThrower{}}, std::runtime_error);
}
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The copy constructor moves the value from `other`

There is a bug in `holder::clone()`:

```
return new holder<T>{std::move(item)};
```

You shouldn't `std::move(item)` if you want to clone it. Your tests all pass because you either used trivial types, or `std::string`s with such a short string that small-string optimization kicks in and never actually causes an allocation that would have been moved.

## Let `clone()` return a `std::unique_ptr`

Use `std::unique_ptr`s as early as possible, this simplifies the code and leaves less chance for manual memory management errors.

## About those friends

> The class is very popular with lots of friends, most of which do very similar things. Is there some way I can consolidate this? Why is `any_cast` a separate function and not part of the class anyway?

Probably because `static_cast<>()` and friends already exist, which could not have been made class members, and `any_cast<>()` just follows that pattern. This is actually nice; it means it's easier to learn with less surprises.

It's not a lot of friends anyway, `std::any` only has three: `std::swap<std::any>()`, `std::any_cast<>()` and `std::make_any<>()`. It's just that each of these can have multiple overloads.

It also allows the convenience of casting a pointer to a `std::any` to a pointer to its value, something which would not be possible with a member function (unless you give that one a different name).

## In-place construction slightly wrong?

The constructor of `holder` that takes a variadic number of parameters uses the following to initialize `item`:

```
item{T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)}
```

I would expect:

```
item(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

Note that a type might have neither move nor copy constructors, or copying/moving might have an overhead you should avoid.

## Unnecessary code

There are a few lines of code that could be removed:

- Instead of defaulting it, you can just omit the destructor of `Any` (but keep the one in `base_holder`, as that one needs to be `virtual`).
- You use the copy-and-swap idiom in the copy constructor, so you don't need to check for `this != &other`.
- The move constructor and move assignment operators can be `default`ed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just had one question, I understand why `std::move()`-ing the item in `clone()` is incorrect (no clue why I did that) but I'm not actually able to write a failing test case for it. I tried the following but the test still passes, although I suppose maybe the implementation leaves a moved-from `std::string` still containing the value. Is the answer to create a custom type where this will not be the case?

Comment: Attempt at failing test: 

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(big_string_test) {
    std::string s = "ljadfjkldkldkldak;slfldafklsdkjlsdafsdaf;jlk;jklddfsa";
    Any a{s};
    Any b{a};

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<std::string>(a), s);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(AnyCast<std::string>(b), s);
}

Comment: The state of an object after a move is such that it can still be safely destructed, but no other guarantee is made. A class can decide to leave the original contents, clear the contents, or anything else. Accessing it afterwards might thus not be safe, but there is no guarantee it will crash. Creating your own custom type would help as you can then control exactly what it does during a move. Also consider using Valgrind or AddressSanitizer when running your tests.

Comment: Incidentally, one of my go-to test cases for in-place construction type methods is: `Any x(std::in_place_type<std::string>, 5, 'a');`  That way, if you accidentally tried using brace-initialization in the implementation, you would catch the bug early that it would interpret this case as wanting the `initializer_list` overload instead of the count and fill character overload.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to G. Sliepen’s excellent answer, and since you asked specifically about how you could simplify the `friend` functions:

#### You Can Turn the `any_cast` Overloads into Wrappers

You could simplify the definitions of the `any_cast` overloads by making them short wrappers.  First (thanks to Daniel Schepler for pointing out a serious mistake), the `any_cast<Any*>` function has different behavior than the others on failure, returning `nullptr`. It’s therefore easier to implement the versions that `throw bad_any_cast;` in terms of this than the other way around:  In fact, the `Any&` overload is specified to return the dereferenced valur of the `Any*` (with certain qualifiers removed and a `static_cast`) and the `Any&&` overload is specified to return `std::move` of that.

This has the advantage that you don’t repeat yourself. You write the check for validity once, in the `Any*` version, and you write the code to check it and possibly throw `bad_any_cast` once, in the `Any&` version. The other implementations that need them, wrap the version that provides them, with no run-time overhead.

Comment: The pointer cast has a different behavior on failure, in that it returns `nullptr` intsead of throwing a bad cast exception.  So probably, you would want to make the pointer version the base version, and then the reference version could be wrappers which check the return value and throw an exception if it's `nullptr`.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh, good catch! I’m in a hurry right now, but I really need to correct that error.